# Execute a non view function from html code

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to execute a python function to execute some background calculations when I click on a button. But using this way didn't work as it redirects me to a url which i dont want to do. The button will just be hidden and the python function
shall be executed.

Html

```
      <button type="button" id="reportproblem" qid={{question.id}} 
         class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-info">
         {% trans "Rapportera Problem"%}
       </button>
       <script type="text/javascript" qid="{{ question.id }}"
            src="/static/js/report_problem.js"> 
       </script>
```

Javacript:

```
   $(document).ready( function () {
      $("#reportproblem").on("click", function(){
      document.getElementById("reportproblem").style.display="none";
      var url = "{% url 'quiz:report_problem' question_id=pk %}'";
      var id = $(this).attr('qid');
      //document.location.href = url.replace('pk', id);
      console.log(url.replace('pk', id))
      $.get(url.replace('pk', id), function (data) {alert("counter updated!");})   -> this one as well redirects to a page
   })
```

My url. Which seemed to be weird since i m using "view" as a parameter to execute the function

```
    url(regex=r'^report_problem/(?P<question_id>[\d.]+)/$',
    view=ReportQuestionProblem,
    name='report_problem'),
```

The function:

```
def ReportQuestionProblem(request):
    print("request:{}".format(request))
```

I get this error for what is above. the current url+ the url in the get:
Here is the log in the browser console

Not Found: /sv/quiz/28-taxi-lagstiftning-prov/take/{% url 'quiz:report_problem' question_id=2427 %}'

Any help?

Comment: You are using `document.location.href = url.replace('pk', id);` which means you want the browser to redirect your request. Is your python code at backend ? Are you trying to make a network call to that API ?

Comment: Yes my python code is at backend and want to call the API but without redirect. the $.get() didnt help.

Comment: What are the API specifics, as in `GET/POST`, urls , headers  ?

Comment: What happens when you do $get ?

Comment: I get redirected to  a page that doesnt exist. the mainurl+{% url 'quiz:report_problem' question_id=pk %}}
I edited the question

Comment: No, `.get` would *not* redirect you. The redirection is being done by your *existing* code, which sets `document.location`. Remove that line and use the commented-out one.

Comment: Yes $.get should not redirect. Remove `document.location.href = url.replace('pk', id);`

Comment: True sorry. I copied the exact error. I get the current_url + the url in the get. see above

Comment: The JS code - or at least the `var url` line - needs to be in a template that is parsed by Django, not a separate .js file.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. No django url should be in a seperate js file. thanks!